# Performance Tuning Mystery

Tags: sql-server, ssis

So I have a SSIS package with a performance problem. I had done 4 runs so far.

Run 1 - Run whole package . It takes 58 seconds . Performance problem replicated.

Run 2 - Run whole package with logging enabled. 66 seconds .

```
01-18-Package   66  10:32:26    10:33:32
Task1   2   10:32:26    10:32:28
Task2   1   10:32:28    10:32:29
Task3   2   10:32:29    10:32:31
Task4   1   10:32:31    10:32:32
Task5   1   10:32:31    10:32:32
Data Flow   59  10:32:32    10:33:31
Task 7  1   10:33:31    10:33:32
```

The bottleneck appears to be the Data Flow.

Run 3. Execute Data flow on its own using right click and execute task. It takes 8 seconds. What ? Running the package with only the data flow task, with play button gives me 9.6 seconds.

Run 4 . Strip out everything from package apart from data flow and run with logging. 52 seconds.

Is the problem the data flow or is this a memory issue ? What should be my logical next step in this investigation ? Logging is not the issue and the Data Flow on its own is not the problem. There is a lookup in the data flow that may use some memory if that is an issue.

> [Find FaultID [33]] Information: The Find FaultID processed 540345
>   rows in the cache. The processing time was 1.623 seconds. The cache
>   used 19452420 bytes of memory.

Comment: I don't think that it is related to the Lookup - since it is embedded in the data flow, the test "package with only the data flow" would be accordingly slow as well. But another question: did you execute the package locally (in Visual Studio) or on a server after deploying it?

Comment: All executions above were locally in viusal studio

Comment: Full cache used for the lookup. I was thinking that the extra memory needed for the lookup may have pushed the memory usage over some threshold.

Comment: What else is in the package except the data flow?

Comment: Just lots of execute sql tasks for validation and required checks. Nothing else that should be crazy intensive in memory or cpu . All remaining tasks run fast and have no issue.

Comment: Try to execute the package with everything in except the data flow. What is the result?
"lot's of SQL tasks" sounds a bit like a slow-down. Visual Studio will have to open a connection, execute the task, return to the package and so on... you might also want to try to execute the package directly on the server (deploy the package to some dummy folder on the server and execute it there) - might provide a much better performance as well.

Comment: UPDATE : Found the problem. Take away the lookup and got the following results. Run 1 - Whole package with logging . 52 seconds. Run 2 Whole package with no logging. 6 seconds ! Ran it twice to make sure !